# How to find a specific discriminated union from the same type,in a sequence,and then return that specific discriminated union if it exists

Tags: f#

I want to check if there is an element of a specific discriminated union in a sequence, and if it exists, I want to return that specific element.

```
 type Shape = 
   | Rectangle of float * float 
   | Circle 
   | Prism 
 let rectangle1 = Rectangle(5.0,1.2)
 let rectangle2 = Rectangle(2.0,1.4)
 let test = [Circle;Prism;rectangle2;rectangle1]

 let getShape shape = 
   match shape with
   | Rectangle(a,b) -> Some(a)
   | _ -> None


let x = 
  if test |> List.exists (fun shape -> (getShape shape) = Some(1.0)) then 
      ???
  elif test|> List.exists (fun shapre -> shape = Circle) then 
      Circle 
  else 
      Prism
```

For the code above, I want to be able to check if there is a Shape of Rectangle with first element of tuple is 1.0

This checking works : `test |> List.exists (fun shape -> (getShape shape) = Some(1.0))`

However, I don't know how to return the "shape" found from that expression.

I want it for sequence, but the example above uses List. I guess it will also apply for sequence.

Answer (score 1):

`List.tryFind` sounds like what you [need](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.tryfind%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D). Also for [Seq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.tryfind%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D).

In your case I believe it would look something like this:

`let x = test |> List.tryFind (fun shape -> (getShape shape) = Some(1.0))`

After that `x` should be of type `Shape`, you'll still need to pattern match to operate on it as a `Rectangle`.

`Rectangle` here is not a type (though it might be represented as one once compiled), but rather a value.